# Issue with getBytes() for accented charaters

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to convert a string with special characters like É into a string with UTF-8 encoding. I tried doing this:

```
String str = "MARIE-HÉLÈNE";
byte sByte[] = str.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
str = new String(sByte,"UTF-8");
```

The problem is, when I do `"É".getBytes("UTF-8")`, I get 63 which is interpreted as '?' when it's being converted to a new string. How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT:** I also noticed that this issue was not reproducible on Eclipse, probably because the text file encoding is usually set to UTF-8.

I tried doing `byte[] str = "MARIE-HÉLÈNE".getBytes("UTF-8")` in http://www.javarepl.com/console.html and got the result `byte[] str = [77, 65, 82, 73, 69, 45, 72, 63, 76, 63, 78, 69]`

Comment: I am surprised that it appears to be this way, but looking at the whole UTF-8 charcter set here:http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm  I cannot find the character you are trying to encode.  If you can do it, I would try UTF-16 or UTF-32 and see if that solves the problem.  Or if not, maybe use a similar letter that is in the UTF-8 character set.

Comment: This code is working fine: see https://ideone.com/UgZCCP (and is kind of a *NOP*), so please edit and post a complete example reproducing your issue

Comment: I have to correct myself.  I see a letter that appears to match after all at c389.  Sorry.

Comment: try this once,  str.getBytes("US-ASCII");

Comment: 63 *already is* '?'. How did you get it? Not via the means you've posted here.

Comment: Agreed with @EJP, as 63 is actually UTF-8 for a question mark, that site you are using is handling the É incorrectly.  I went to the same site and got the same result.  The site is just not doing the full UTF-8 character set correctly

Comment: EJP @WDS - I face this problem even when I use the snippet above to create an XML document with UTF-8 encoding. The document has funny chars in place of accented chars.

Comment: @Anirudh `str.getBytes("US-ASCII"); ` returns the same output.

Comment: @ShwethaDurgashankar See Andreas's answer. That's what you get from that code. You haven't answered my question as to how *you* got what you got.

Comment: @EJP as I had mentioned in my editI tried doing byte[] str = "MARIE-HÉLÈNE".getBytes("UTF-8") in http://www.javarepl.com/console.html and got the result byte[] str = [77, 65, 82, 73, 69, 45, 72, 63, 76, 63, 78, 69]. As you can see, 63 is returned for the char È. I also observed this behavior while using the code snipped to create an XML document.

Answer (score 5):

This kind of error happens when information about the encoding of the source file is not given to the compiler (javac) properly. If the encoding of your source file is UTF-8, compile the file like the following.

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 E.java
```

The following is another example for the case where the encoding of the source file is UTF-16 Big Endian.

```
javac -encoding UTF-16BE E.java
```

I've already confirmed that the program below properly shows "0xC3 0x89". So, there is no problem in your code.

```
public class E
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] bytes = "É".getBytes("UTF-8");

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i)
        {
            System.out.format("0x%02X ", (byte)(bytes[i]));
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`"É".getBytes("UTF-8")` returns a `byte[]` of **2** bytes: `c3 89`.

`"MARIE-HÉLÈNE"` is `4d 41 52 49 45 2d 48 c3 89 4c c3 88 4e 45`.

```
4d 41 52 49 45 2d 48 c3 89 4c c3 88 4e 45
M  A  R  I  E  -  H  É     L  È     N  E
```

Converting the bytes back using `new String(bytes,"UTF-8")` will restore the original string.